# URLSessions or AlamoFire for downloading a webpage that updates once a day?

Tags: ios, swift

One of my view controllers decodes and prints html from a web page. I've done searches on stackoverflow and in example project on github and it seems that people are using Alamofire with Swiftsoup to do this.

I'm a beginner but I am trying to understand why I would need AlamoFire when I can just use URLSessions? Is it better to use Alamofire?

My use case is simple, I think. If I use Alamofire,

```
let getURL = "https://www.someurl.com/extension"

    Alamofire.request(getURL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate(contentType: ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]).response { (response) in

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            do {
                parseHTML()
            }
        }
     }
```

If I use URLSessions, I think it would like this:

```
let httpURL = URL(string: "https://www.someurl.com/extension")!
    let httpTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: httpURL) {
     (data, response, error) in
     guard let validData = data, error == nil else {
     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     print("Error getting paragraph\n") })
     return
     }

    var results = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Unable to read Paragraph HTML\n"
     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("Correctly read from Paragraph HTML\n")
        parseHTML()
     })
     }
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async(execute: {
     httpTask.resume()
     })
```

Side question: Is Swiftsoup the go to for decoding HTML? Is there something built in that can be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire/AFNetworking (AFNetworking is the objective-c version) gained traction as an alternative to Apple's NSURLConnection class, that was much more low level and involved a lot of boilerplate code. It was not as easy to establish a download task or anything with NSURLConnection, AFNetworking (at the time) made it easier to perform the tasks like in your question without having to write too much code.

Around iOS7, Apple released NSURLSession to replace NSURLConnection, which made it quite similar to how AlamoFire do things. At this point personally, I feel that using NSURLSession/URLSession is fine and straightforward enough. Maybe AlamoFire is a bit easier to use but overall they are similar. The only times I end up moving towards AlamoFire these days is when I face some type of limitation.

So tl;dr, pre iOS7, AFNetworking was a much easier and straightforward way of working with download tasks. Post iOS7 URLSessions became easier to work with and set up.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I'm building my first app and I wanted to use best practices and it seemed like using something native was a better option than a dependency but I didn't understand the differences in functionality. I will run with URLSessions because I'm just downloading html from a single webpage.

Comment: @bhealth yeah you should be more than fine with URLSessions. In my previous project, I ended up switching to Alamofire once I started needed downloads to continue working in the background. I think there is some additional configuration needed to do them with URLSessions.